# iOS webbrowser will close the websocket connection automatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, websocket

iOS webbrowser will close the connection automatically?

I am using HTML5 websocket sample, run it in iOS browser.

I found that the connection will be closed after few minutes(error code:**1006**):

`The connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or receiving a Close control frame`

But it does not appear in the other platform(android, linux and windows desktop).

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a problem of iOS, not the server, because the connection will not close automatically if i set the screen lock time to `Never`

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue in ios mobile. Is there any way to re establish the connection again?